# Implicit returns from single-expression closures in swift playground

Tags: swift

According to THE Swift book from Apple, instead of

```
let names = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]
var reversed = sorted(names, { s1, s2 in return s1 > s2 })
```

because the closure's body contains a single expression *s1 > s2* that returns a Bool, there is no ambiguity, so the *return* keyword can be omitted:

```
reversed = sorted(names, { s1, s2 in s1 > s2 })
```

Well, this does not work in Playground.  The error in Playground says *Ambiguous use of operator '>'*.

**Update**: Similarly, this

```
reversed = sorted(names, { $0 > $1 })
```

does not work.  Same error.  This

```
reversed = sorted(names, { return $0 > $1 })
```

does.

**Update 2**: After seeing Mike S's answer, I am convinced the bug might be due to Swift String and NSString.  I tried

```
let nums = [3, 5, 1, 2, 10, 9]
var dec = sorted(nums, { n1, n2 in n1 > n2 })
var inc = sorted(nums, { n1, n2 in n1 < n2 })
```

They all worked with or without the import statement.  The work around for String is not to bad since now we just have to type return when we want to compare String using the > operator.

So what can be the explanation here (have not checked in a normal project)?

Comment: hehe, perfect example from the swift manual - doesn't work in a project either.

Comment: I've noticed this as well.  They may have removed that particular short cut.

Comment: Interestingly, these all work with the `<` operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is actually with comparing `String`s. An `Array` of `Int`s works just fine with either the `<` or `>` operators, but with an `Array` of `Strings`s, only the `<` operator will work (as of Xcode 6.1 GM anyway).

To show that it's an issue with `String` comparison, try this in a Playground:

```
import Foundation
let result1 = "Chris" < "Alex" // false
let result2 = "Chris" > "Alex" // error: ambiguous use of operator '>'
```

If you open the console output of the Playground, you'll also see:

```
Playground execution failed: <EXPR>:17:9: error: ambiguous use of operator '>'
"Chris" > "Alex"
        ^
Foundation.>:1:6: note: found this candidate
func >(lhs: String, rhs: NSString) -> Bool
     ^
Foundation.>:1:6: note: found this candidate
func >(lhs: NSString, rhs: String) -> Bool
```

So, the issue seems to be that the compiler is having trouble determining if `"Chris"` and `"Alex"` are `String`s or `NSString`s.

Further, if you take out the default `import` statement at the top of the Playground, everything will work fine because `NSString` isn't imported and, therefore, not bridged to `String`:

```
let result1 = "Chris" < "Alex" // false
let result2 = "Chris" > "Alex" // true
```

Or, to use the code in the question (no `import`):

```
let names = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]
let reversed = sorted(names, { $0 > $1 }) // [Alex, Barry, Chris, Daniella, Ewa]
```

What I can't answer though, is why the `>` **does** work if you use a `return` statement in the closure passed to `sorted`.

Comment: I'm convinced.  Good enough answer for me.  Seems like a bug in the compiler.  The work around is really "painful" because I have to type return everytime now.